# Understanding type-directed resolution in Haskell with existential types

Tags: haskell

I've been learning Haskell and encountered a point of confusion. When defining an existential type with a custom type class, it seems that other algebraic data types, which are instances of the same custom type class, share the same structure from the type class.

Here's an example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class MyShow a where
    myShow :: a -> String

data Showable = forall a. MyShow a => Showable a

instance MyShow Showable where
    myShow (Showable a) = myShow a

data CustomType = CustomInt Int | CustomString String

instance MyShow CustomType where
    myShow (CustomInt i) = "CustomInt " ++ show i
    myShow (CustomString s) = "CustomString " ++ s

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let intShowable = Showable (CustomInt 5)
        stringShowable = Showable (CustomString "Hello, Haskell!")

    putStrLn $ myShow intShowable
    putStrLn $ myShow stringShowable
```

In the above code, my concern is with the following part:

```hs
instance MyShow Showable where
    myShow (Showable a) = myShow a
```

I believe `myShow a` is not a recursive function; instead, it acts as a placeholder for `myShow` functions that are instances implemented in the `MyShow` type class.

I think `myShow a` is a placeholder that will be replaced with the appropriate function based on the relevant types when the compiler compiles the program, and it operates as type-directed resolution.

Is my understanding correct, or is there a different interpretation of this behavior?

I hope the clear explanation. Thanks for your patient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. A common implementation of typeclass constraints uses *hidden dictionary* arguments to pass around the relevant typeclass methods implementations.

Your code is roughly compiled as the one below. Note how the code below has no typeclasses.

```
data Showable = forall a. Showable (a -> String) a
                                   ------------- hidden "dictionary" field

-- no longer an instance, now a plain function
myShow_Showable (Showable otherMyShow a) = otherMyShow a
                          ----------- we call the hidden field, no recursion

data CustomType = CustomInt Int | CustomString String

-- no longer an instance, now a plain function    
myShow_CustomType (CustomInt i) = "CustomInt " ++ show i
myShow_CustomType (CustomString s) = "CustomString " ++ s

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let intShowable = Showable myShow_CustomType (CustomInt 5)
                               ----------------- added by the compiler
        stringShowable = Showable myShow_CustomType (CustomString "Hello, Haskell!")
                                  -----------------

    putStrLn $ myShow_Showable intShowable
               --------------- the compiler chose the right instance
    putStrLn $ myShow_Showable stringShowable
               ---------------
```

The compiler uses type-directed reasoning to infer the values of the hidden dictionary arguments/fields. You can directly observe this if you compile a program asking GHC to "dump the Core" with the `-ddump-simpl` flag (warning: a lot of low-level code will be printed. Core is somehow Haskell-like but not so easy to understand at first).

Answer (score 2):

@chi's answer alludes to an implementation that uses hidden dictionary arguments. Here is how you can observe this in GHC.

`myShow` is not a single function, but a *family* of functions. You can make this explicit by enabling the `TypeApplications`. For example,  you can define the `CustomType` instance as

```
instance MyShow CustomType where
    myShow (CustomInt i) = "CustomInt " ++ myShow i -- "recursive"
    myShow (CustomString s) = "CustomString " ++ s
```

and add an additional, trivial instance for `Int`:

```
instance MyShow Int where
    myShow = show
```

(Doing something similar for `String`/`[Char]` but not other lists requires some other shenanigans that are beyond the scope of this answer.)

You can see that `myShow` applied to a `CustomType` is a different function than `myShow` applied to an `Int`:

```
> :set -XTypeApplications
> :t myShow @CustomType
myShow @CustomType :: CustomType -> String
> :t myShow @Int
myShow @Int :: Int -> String
```